# PHP MySQL Update returns success, but no rows are changed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to `update` my database through `PHP` but it's not working. Here is the function I am using. This is all `PHP`

```
function update($query, $values = "") {

        $success = false;
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);

        if (is_array($values)) {
            $success = $statement->execute($values);
            print("\nIt is an array");
        } else {
            $success = $statement->execute();
        }

        $statement->closeCursor();
        return $success;
}
```

And here is how I am calling it.

```
$data=array();
    $data[] = $FirstName;
    $data[] = $LastName;
    $data[] = $Email;
    $data[] = $AccessLevel;
    $data[] = $UserID;

try{
    $thisDatabase->db->beginTransaction();
    $query ="UPDATE Users SET FirstName=?, LastName=?, ContactEmail=?, AccessLevel=? WHERE UserID=?";
    $userData = $thisDatabase->update($query,$data);
}catch (PDOExecption $e){
    $thisDatabase->db->rollback();
    print "There was a problem with the query";
}
```

This function returns `1` (when I print out `$userData`).

Here is the `$data` array that I am passing it.

```
Array(
    [0] => Jon
    [1] => Smith
    [2] => Jon@none.com
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
)
```

If I run the query in `PHPmyadmin` it works. **Note:** I do have to add quotes to the columns stored as strings.
`UPDATE Users SET FirstName='Jon', LastName='Smith', ContactEmail='Jon@none.com', AccessLevel=1 WHERE UserID=2`

So, does anyone have any ideas where my issue is or how I can go about finding it?

---

For reference, I use a similar function for `select` statements, and it works perfectly.

```
function select($query, $values = "") {

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);

        if (is_array($values)) {
            $statement->execute($values);
        } else {
            $statement->execute();
        }
        $recordSet = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        $statement->closeCursor();
        return $recordSet;
}
```

Comment: where and how is `$data` defined? There needs to be matching arrays for those.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added it. It is set before the `try`/`catch`.

Comment: `PDOExecption` is that your real code? It's a typo and should read as `PDOException`

Comment: ^ you never responded to that comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are correct, I did not. I will fix the typo - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not committing your transaction. Therefore, changes that you make with your `UPDATE` are not being actually saved in the database.

Add `$thisDatabase->db->commit()` after the `try...catch` block. This, of course, shouldn't be called if the transaction needs to be rolled back, so return from the function in the `catch` block, or add a flag.

Comment: Geeze.. That's so frustrating. Thanks for your help. I had that at one point but looks like I accidently deleted it somewhere along the way.